# How to export to audio in following code(from a model)?

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, model

I am trying to execute the following code in this document. https://github.com/magenta/midi-ddsp.
The one I am trying is the `Advance Usage` part. However, the `synthesized_audio_changed` in this doc is just an array, and I can't find the way about how to export the audio.

Moreover,
it shows `Generating:   0%|          | 0/2712 [00:00<?, ?it/s]` in the beginning. But my code is as same as theirs, so I am not sure whether it is the system incompatible problem (maybe it could just run in Colab?). Here is my code, and I just copy half of them, because the upper part is similar with the later part, just the difference of the parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from midi_ddsp.utils.midi_synthesis_utils import synthesize_mono_midi, conditioning_df_to_audio
from midi_ddsp.utils.inference_utils import get_process_group
from midi_ddsp.midi_ddsp_synthesize import load_pretrained_model
from midi_ddsp.data_handling.instrument_name_utils import INST_NAME_TO_ID_DICT

# -----MIDI Synthesis-----
midi_file = '/Users/midi-ddsp/midi_example/ode_to_joy.mid'
# Load pre-trained model
synthesis_generator, expression_generator = load_pretrained_model()
# Synthesize with violin:
instrument_name = 'violin'
instrument_id = INST_NAME_TO_ID_DICT[instrument_name]
# Run model prediction
midi_audio, midi_control_params, midi_synth_params, conditioning_df = synthesize_mono_midi(synthesis_generator,
                                                                                           expression_generator,
                                                                                           midi_file, instrument_id,
                                                                                           output_dir=None)

synthesized_audio = midi_audio  # The synthesized audio

# -----Adjust note expression controls and re-synthesize-----

# Make all notes weak vibrato:
conditioning_df_changed = conditioning_df.copy()
note_vibrato = conditioning_df_changed['vibrato']

conditioning_df_changed['vibrato'] = (conditioning_df['vibrato'].values) * 0.1
# Re-synthesize
midi_audio_changed, midi_control_params_changed, midi_synth_params_changed = conditioning_df_to_audio(
  synthesis_generator, conditioning_df_changed, tf.constant([instrument_id]))

synthesized_audio_changed = midi_audio_changed  # The synthesized audio
```